# How to scale vector graphics properly?

Tags: android, drawing, vector-graphics

I am learning how to use the vector drawing API and I have the following problem.

I am drawing lines and arcs on a canvas, and the View containing this canvas can be pinched zoomed. When zoomed in, the line scale perfectly but the arcs don't.

public class MyView extends View {

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    rects = new RectF[1000];

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save(); 

    canvas.translate(mOffset.x * mScaleFactor + canvas.getWidth() * 0.5f, mOffset.y * mScaleFactor + canvas.getHeight() * 0.5f);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

    canvas.drawLine(-10, -5, 10, 5, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(10, -10, -10, 10, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    RectF f = new RectF(-50, -50, 50, 50);
    canvas.drawArc(f, 0.f, 360.f, true, paint);
    canvas.restore(); 
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener       
    {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.01f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 100.0f));
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this just in a right way, you code on my device works great.[image]

Comment: You can not zoom in the vector infinitely, there are limits with canvas,  you must trim the invisible parts of the arc, in many programs achieving this by draw a multiline polygon( and trim the polygon edges by view frame) instead of a arc.